# Mazes map Fallout 76

Tags: fallout-76

in TES and previous Fallouts, whenever you entered some maze (cave,house,factory) you would be able to switch between the world map and the local map of this maze. I cannot find this option in Fallout 76. Could someone tell if it even exists?

I play on PC if it matters

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that the local maps do not exist in this Fallout (at least at this time). The map is completely different than the previous recent Fallout games, with this map being colored with actual pictures of landmarks on it, and it isn't on your Pipboy either.

Previous Fallouts had a "Map" tab within your Pipboy, and when you were looking at the map, you had the ability to toggle to the local area map. This tab in the Pipboy is completely gone now, with the map being reachable via the pause button on a controller or <kbd>Esc</kbd> on a keyboard instead.